# Bucket name validation fails in Boto3 in a Junyper notebook

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Been running into an error with my S3 bucket and folder using Boto3 to download a file into a Junyper notebook. This is the code that generates the error, which I'm assuming I'm using the wrong approach:

```
# EDIT: S3 bucket and folder where you uploaded file.zip
BUCKET='arn:aws:s3:mybucket'
BUCKET_PATH='/dataset'

# DO NOT EDIT: Name of zip and relative path on managed notebook
FILES='dataverse_files'
FILES_EXT='dataverse_files.zip'
BASE_DIR='../

s3 = boto3.client('s3)
s3.download_file(BUCKET, BUCKET_PATH+'/'+FILE_EXT,BASE_DIR+FILES_EXT)
```

Then I'm getting this error:

ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid bucket name "arn:aws:s3:mybucket": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$"

I've tried several combinations of changing the bucket to full path, ARN and bucket path to several options and I'm still running into the issues. Any recommendations?

Comment: From the error message, it sounds like you could change the bucket name to `BUCKET='mybucket'` . Does that work?

Comment: @NickODell is right. Your bucket name is "mybucket". The alternative would be to use what is called an 'arn' but that's probably not something you want to get into at this point. Keep it simple. Boto3 takes care of the complicated stuff for you.

Comment: If you have to go the ARN way for some reason, it should be `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket` if I remeber the path correctly. If you don't know why you might need this - forget about ARN and just use a bucket name as suggested by @NickODell.

Comment: Thanks @NickODell for the tip, I changed my file with the following: BUCKET='mybucket'
BUCKET_PATH='/dataset' but now I'm getting this error: ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found...not 100% sure with the errors Boto3 is giving me...

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, I simply needed to remove the "/" in front of the "dataset"in the BUCKET_PATH variable.

Comment: You got it. Keep it simple, boto3 will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution**:

```
BUCKET='mybucket'
BUCKET_PATH='dataset'
```

You don't need to start or end your BUCKET_PATH with a forward slash if it is a single 'directory'.